# What is the difference between /tmp and /var/tmp?

Tags: directory-structure, fhs, tmp

On most [FHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) systems, there is a `/tmp` folder as well as a `/var/tmp` folder. What is the functional difference between the two?

Comment: Here is a similar question on Server Fault: [Difference and correct usage for /tmp and /var/tmp](http://serverfault.com/q/220000/84914)

Answer (score 172, accepted):

`/tmp` is meant as fast (possibly small) storage with a short lifetime. Many systems clean `/tmp` very fast - on some systems it is even mounted as RAM-disk. `/var/tmp` is normally located on a physical disk, is larger and can hold temporary files for a longer time. Some systems also clean `/var/tmp`, but less often.

Also note that `/var/tmp` might not be available in the early boot-process, as `/var` and/or `/var/tmp` may be mountpoints. Thus it is a little bit comparable to the difference between `/bin` and `/usr/bin`. The first is available during early boot - the latter after the system has mounted everything. So most boot-scripts will use `/tmp` and not `/var/tmp` for temporary files.

Another (upcoming) location on Linux for temporary files is `/dev/shm`.

Comment: I find it a bit ironic that `/bin` and `/usr/bin` are actually the same these days (symlinks). ;-)

Comment: @Felix Not on all distributions yet. But Linux is moving that way. Propably because disks get bigger and bigger.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/220000/difference-and-correct-usage-for-tmp-and-var-tmp

Comment: So, How should `/tmp` and `/var/tmp` should be sized considering `/tmp` is available before `/var/tmp` be mounted?

Comment: @Israel 4 GB should be enough for each. But there has to be a policy not to use tmp-directies for long  lasting storage.

Answer (score 44):

`/tmp` may be, and sometimes is, cleaned on reboot. `/var/tmp` is preserved between reboots.

See [the Wikipedia article on the FHS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard).

Comment: */tmp* may even clean the files created by a process right after it has exited!

Answer (score 31):

[POSIX Base Specifications, Issue 7 on */tmp*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap10.html):

> The following directory shall exist on conforming systems and shall be
>   used as described:
>
> **/tmp**
>
> A directory made available for applications that need a place to create temporary files. Applications shall be allowed to create files
>   in this directory, but shall not assume that such files are preserved
>   between invocations of the application.

[The File Hierarchy Standard 2.3 on */tmp*](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#TMPTEMPORARYFILES):

> The */tmp* directory must be made available for programs that require
>   temporary files.
>
> Programs must not assume that any files or directories in */tmp* are
>   preserved between invocations of the program.
>
> **Rationale**
>
> IEEE standard P1003.2 (POSIX, part 2) makes requirements that are
>   similar to the above section.
>
> Although data stored in */tmp* may be deleted in a site-specific manner,
>   it is recommended that files and directories located in */tmp* be
>   deleted whenever the system is booted.
>
> FHS added this recommendation on the basis of historical precedent and
>   common practice, but did not make it a requirement because system
>   administration is not within the scope of this standard.

POSIX does not specify */var/tmp*.
[The FHS does though](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#VARTMPTEMPORARYFILESPRESERVEDBETWEE):

> The */var/tmp* directory is made available for programs that require
>   temporary files or directories that are preserved between system
>   reboots. Therefore, data stored in */var/tmp* is more persistent than
>   data in */tmp*.
>
> Files and directories located in */var/tmp* must not
>   be deleted when the system is booted. Although data stored in
>   */var/tmp* is typically deleted in a site-specific manner, it is recommended that deletions occur at a less frequent interval than
>   */tmp*.

Answer (score 16):

They have the same purpose and functionality.  Every version of UNIX/Linux will handle these directories differently.  Historically, before the advent of RAM/swap based filesystems, you had disk-less systems where the `/` and `/usr` filesystems would be read-only and `/var` (variable) would be read-write.  The `/tmp` name would be a symbolic link to `/var/tmp`.  Later, disk-less systems fell out of style, disk space became cheaper (to have larger root filesytems) and technology allowed for filesystems mounted from memory instead of disk.  The `/var/tmp` directory fell out of style, but is still used by some programs.

These days, more security are set up by default on `/tmp`, like `g+s,+t` permissions, but not on `/var/tmp`.  Additionally, `/var/tmp` is rarely mounted from RAM or swap.

Comment: on my debian and fedora systems, /tmp and /var/tmp have the same mode - `a+rwx+t` - and no `g+s`.