# What can go wrong if /var/tmp is on a temporary filesystem?

Tags: filesystems, directory-structure, tmp

I have read that I should not mount /var/tmp as a temporary filesystem (e.g., as tmpfs), because files in /var/tmp must not be deleted on reboot.  Is that correct?

Suppose I did mount /var/tmp as a tmpfs, so its contents are deleted on every reboot.  Would that be bad?  If yes, what could go wrong?  How bad would it be?

Comment: @JMoore, I'm asking about `/var/tmp`, not about `/tmp`.  My apologies if this was unclear.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Files in `/var/tmp` are expected to be persistent across reboots. From [the
FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/2.2/fhs-5.15.html):

> The /var/tmp directory is made available for programs that require temporary
>   files or directories that are preserved between system reboots. Therefore,
>   data stored in /var/tmp is more persistent than data in /tmp.

Files in `/var/tmp` are often cache files or temporary files that should not
disappear in the event of a sudden power failure. They cannot be expected to
live forever though. It is common to [clear old
files](http://www.unixguide.net/hp/faq/5.11.2.shtml) from `/var/tmp` on a
schedule.

Here are some examples of `/var/tmp`'s usage:

- Some implementations of vi (e.g. `nvi`) put their crash recovery files in `/var/tmp`. If that's a temporary filesystem, you don't get a chance of recovering anything. Vim puts its crash recovery files in the same directory as the file being edited.
- I use [a Firefox plugin](http://5digits.org/pentadactyl/) that allows me to
  edit text fields in Vim. To accomplish this, the plugin creates a temporary
  file in `/var/tmp` (`/tmp` is the default though) and passes the file to Vim.
  If my computer loses power while I am using this feature, my writing will be
  safe and sound in `/var/tmp`.
- Text editing tools such as `ex` and `sudoedit` put temporary files in
  `/var/tmp`. If `/var/tmp` was mounted as tmpfs, you would risk losing data to
  unexpected power failures.
- The `git-archive(1)` manpage has the following example.

> git archive --format=tar --prefix=junk/ HEAD | (cd /var/tmp/ && tar xf -)
>   Create a tar archive that contains the contents of the latest commit on
>   the current branch, and extract it in the /var/tmp/junk directory.

It is possible that the `/var/tmp` directory was chosen so that the extracted
archive contents would not be lost to sudden power failure.

Since `/var/tmp` is cleared periodically but never unexpectedly, it is common
to store temporary logs and test databases there. For example, in the `arpd`
manpage, `/var/tmp` is used as the location of a test database for the sake
of some examples.

> arpd -b /var/tmp/arpd.db
>    Start arpd to collect gratuitous ARP, but not messing with kernel functionality.
>   
>   In summary, your system is unlikely to incur severe damage if you mount
>   `/var/tmp` as a tmpfs. Doing so may be undesirable though as you would risk
>   losing information to power failures and reboots.

Comment: See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30489/what-is-the-difference-between-tmp-and-var-tmp

Comment: @D.W. Also `/var/tmp` is likely to be larger than `/tmp`, so some applications expect to put large temporary files there. If `/var/tmp` is on tmpfs, your system may run out of memory or start thrashing.