# mount /var/log as tmpfs in Linux

Tags: linux, logs, tmpfs

My current laptop hard drive (Seagate ST940818SM) is slow (max 42MB/s R/W speed) and out of space. Mounting `/tmp` and `/var/tmp` as tmpfs does a lot of performance improvement. So is it safe to mount `/var/log` as tmpfs?

I don't care about logs on my laptop. Will it improve battery backup time somewhat? As log files are on RAM, this allows complete hard drive spin down during no activity period.

Comment: Do you write much to /var/log anyway? Also, some programs write to *subdirectories* under /var/log and may be upset when these suddenly disappear after a reboot.

Comment: It might not be a good idea to mount `/var/tmp` as tmps: [reference](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86302/111181)

Answer (score 9):

Technically, you can mount `/var/log` as tmpfs. You'd need to be sure that `/var/log` is mounted before `syslogd` starts, but that's the case by default on most distributions since they support `/var` on a separate partition.

You'll obviously lose all logs, which I guarantee will be a problem one day. Logs are there for a purpose — there're rarely needed, but they're there when they're needed. For example, if your system crashes, what was it doing before the crash? Since when has this package been incstalled? When did I print this document? etc.

You won't gain much disk space: logs don't take much space relative to a hard disk. Check how much space they use on your system; I'd expect something like 0.1% of the disk size.

You won't gain any performance. Logs amount to a negligible part of disk bandwidth on a normal desktop-type configuration.

The only gain would be to allow the disk to stay down, rather than spin up all the time to write new log entries. Spinning the disk down doesn't save much electricity if any: the hard disk is only a small part of a laptop power consumption, and spinning up requires a power surge. Furthermore spin cycles wear down the disk, so don't spin down too often. The main reason to spin down is the noise.

Rather than putting logs on tmpfs, arrange for your disk not to spin up when a file is written. Install [Laptop Mode](http://www.samwel.tk/laptop_mode), which causes writes to disk to be suspended while the disk is spun down — only a full write buffer, an explicit sync or a disk read will spin the disk back up.

Depending on your configuration, you may need to instruct the syslog daemon not to call `sync` after each write. With the traditional syslog daemon, make sure that all file names in `/etc/syslog.conf` have `-` before them, e.g.

```
auth,authpriv.*         -/var/log/auth.log
```

With rsyslog, also make sure that log file names have `-` before them; the log files are configured in `/etc/rsyslog.conf` and `/etc/rsyslog.d/*`.

Comment: Probably, if something go wrong, it is easy to just comment out the line with tmpfs in `/etc/fstab`. In fact, I can think of the case when one needs to move logs to *tmpfs* — I just have one ☺ It is when the system is installed to a cheap usb stick, they tends to have very slow IO.

Comment: @Hi-Angel Logs can be useful when investigating **past** events. Commenting out the `fstab` entry will only allow to investigate **future** events. That might make a big difference.

Comment: This can be useful when reducing the number of writes on a drive to increase the lifespan (especially for embedded systems with SD-cards).

Comment: "You won't gain much disk space: logs don't take much space relative to a hard disk." My logs grow at a rate of a few GB per hour.

Comment: But in this case ram disk wont save you !