# Can I mount `/var/log/journal` as `tmpfs`?

Tags: linux, fstab, systemd-journald, tmpfs

I have read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211019/mount-var-log-as-tmpfs-in-linux) question, but it discusses `syslog` and my question is about `journald`. Can I mount `/var/log/journal` as tmpfs using `fstab`, or will `journald` be run (and therefore maybe write to the directory) before the kernel reads `fstab`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want journald's logs stored on disk then use the `Storage=volatile` setting in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` - there's no need to mess around with mounting /var/log/journal as tmpfs.

From `man journald.conf`:

> **Storage=**
>
> Controls where to store journal data. One of "volatile",
> "persistent", "auto" and "none".
>
> If "**volatile**", journal log data will be stored only in memory,
> i.e. below the /run/log/journal hierarchy (which is created if
> needed).
>
> If "**persistent**", data will be stored preferably on disk, i.e.
> below the /var/log/journal hierarchy (which is created if
> needed), with a fallback to /run/log/journal (which is created
> if needed), during early boot and if the disk is not writable.
>
> "**auto**" behaves like "persistent" if the /var/log/journal
> directory exists, and "volatile" otherwise (the existence of
> the directory controls the storage mode).
>
> "**none**" turns off all storage, all log data received will
> be dropped (but forwarding to other targets, such as the
> console, the kernel log buffer, or a syslog socket will still
> work).
>
> Defaults to "auto" in the default journal namespace, and
> "persistent" in all others.

Comment: "Ideas are not property to begin with", I enjoyed reading this :) You indeed guessed my intention to prevent it storing logs on disk. Thank you for your answer!