# When to clean up /var/tmp?

Tags: tmp, fhs, standard, disk-cleanup, var

`/var/tmp` is not defined in POSIX, but is [defined in FHS](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.html#vartmpTemporaryFilesPreservedBetwee):

```
5.15. /var/tmp : Temporary files preserved between system reboots
5.15.1. Purpose
The /var/tmp directory is made available for programs that 
require temporary files or directories that are preserved between 
system reboots. Therefore, data stored in /var/tmp is more 
persistent than data in /tmp.

Files and directories located in /var/tmp must not be deleted
when the system is booted. Although data stored in /var/tmp is 
typically deleted in a site-specific manner, it is recommended 
that deletions occur at a less frequent interval than /tmp.
```

This is a very difficult definition for real life situations.
A package does not use `/tmp`, because the files should not be deleted on reboot for some reason.

If a package fails to cleanup its remains in `/tmp` the distribution/admin can safely clean at reboot.

When and how should we clean up `/var/tmp`? What can packages and software developers expect from `/var/tmp`?

Do we have to clean `/var/tmp` after `n` reboots?

(see also [What can go wrong if /var/tmp is on a temporary filesystem?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86297/what-can-go-wrong-if-var-tmp-is-on-a-temporary-filesystem) and [What is the difference between /tmp and /var/tmp?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30489/what-is-the-difference-between-tmp-and-var-tmp))

Comment: Cleaning up after `n` reboots violates FHS and introduces an uncertainty to applications as to when their files will not be preserved. Perhaps something based on `find /var/tmp/ -mtime +30` will be more consistent.

Comment: @doneal24 no, this would be a violation of `Files and directories located in /var/tmp must not be deleted when the system is booted.` And who knows that a reboot is more often than once in 30 days?

Comment: I explicitly said not to delete after `n` reboots as this violates FHS. Where in FHS does it state that files may not be deleted after a certain number of days? The `find` is completely independent of any reboot schedule.

Comment: *Although data stored in /var/tmp is typically deleted in a site-specific manner*. I don't see how this question could be answered ... Maybe if a specific package is involved, otherwise it seems pretty clear that there is no general rule.

Comment: IMHO the description is wrong. Permanent temporary files makes no sense. It's used for temporary storage of "large" amounts of data. Too many apps never clean after themselves (eg. flatpak). systemd-tmpfiles is suppose to clean it but it doesn't work well. I wipe it on boot regardless, YMMV.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. I take home that the definition is not very useful here and filed a bug for improvement so that it becomes clearer in future FHS https://bugs.linuxfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1444

Comment: Since data is being deleted in a `site-specific manner`, I'm not quite sure how a change to the document will address procedures on your specific site.

Comment: I would read the FHS as saying the retention time is meant to be at the admin's policy based upon their specific needs with the only restriction being that the deletion cannot be done by an init script.