# Moving /tmp from ramdisk to other partition

Tags: debian, tmp, ramdisk

Due to a deficit of RAM on Debian, I need to move /tmp to SSD drive.  But I still can't figure it out, how to do that so the programs that use it will still access it under /tmp path.

So basically, what I want to achieve is move /tmp from ramdisk to for example /home/tmp.  And be able to access it through /tmp

Comment: make link to your destination from /tmp

Comment: Please note consumer SSDs will shut down or go Read-Only when you reach their specified number of writes, as described in https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/intel-ssd-600p-nvme-endurance-testing,4826.html so I'd watch your number of writes and budget for a replacement SSD accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
systemctl mask tmp.mount
```

This command tells `systemd` not to mount the RAM-based filesystem (`tmpfs`) on /tmp.  To apply the change, you must then reboot the system.

In most cases this is all you need to do.  It is not necessary to redirect /tmp to /home/tmp, or anywhere else.  This method is recommended in official [systemd documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/APIFileSystems/#whyareyoutellingmeallthisijustwanttogetridofthetmpfsbackedtmp) --

> #### I just want to get rid of the tmpfs backed /tmp!
>
> You have three options:
>
> 1. Disable any mounting on /tmp so that it resides on the same physical file system as the root directory. For that, execute
>      `systemctl mask tmp.mount`
> 2. Mount a different, physical file system to /tmp. For that, simply create an entry for it in /etc/fstab as you would do for any other
>      file system.
> 3. Keep /tmp but increase/decrease the size of it. For that, also just create an entry for it in /etc/fstab as you would do for any other
>      tmpfs file system, and use the right size= option.

#### Why is it not necessary to redirect /tmp e.g. to /home/tmp?

The above should leave /tmp as a writeable directory inside `/` (the root filesystem).  Software for Debian or most other Linux distributions *should* only use /tmp for a small set of files, so I would not worry about running out of space in the root filesystem.  This requirement mostly appears to derive from the idea that /tmp may be a RAM filesystem :-).

- https://systemd.io/TEMPORARY_DIRECTORIES.html
- [What is the difference between /tmp and /var/tmp?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30489/what-is-the-difference-between-tmp-and-var-tmp/233551#233551) [unix.stackexchange.com]

You do not need to worry that /tmp will fill up with stale files over time.  /tmp is automatically cleaned up at boot time:

```
$ cat /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.

# See tmpfiles.d(5) for details

# Clear tmp directories separately, to make them easier to override
D /tmp 1777 root root -
#q /var/tmp 1777 root root 30d

# There are more lines here, but they are not important to this answer
# ...
```