# How to set up /var/tmp

Tags: tmp

This is a very stupid question but how can we set up /var/tmp? Is there a special way to do it or will just creating the directory suffice?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30489/what-is-the-difference-between-tmp-and-var-tmp @Gearge M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like `/tmp`, it should have the sticky bit set so that files can only be delete by their owner, and it should be world-writable:

```
mkdir /var/tmp && chmod 01777 /var/tmp
```